# CSS custom tag shape - extra line

Tags: html, css

Please refer to this link.https://codepen.io/wbeeftink/pen/dIaDH. If you zoom out or zoom in you will see that the tag has an extra line sticking out at the bottom. Please refer to the screenshot. [image]

[image]

Could someone please let me know how this could be fixed. Or is there a different way to create such tags?
This is the code that I use

HTML

```
<span class="tag">HTML</span>
```

CSS

```
.tag {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 23px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
}

.tag::before {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  content: '';
  height: 6px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  top: 10px;
}

.tag::after {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #eee;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change style of `.tag::after` from `right: 0` to `left: 100%`.

```css
body {
  font: 12px/1.5 'PT Sans', serif;
  margin: 25px;
}

.tags {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding: 0;
}

.tags li {
  float: left; 
}

.tag {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 23px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
}

.tag::before {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  content: '';
  height: 6px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  top: 10px;
}

.tag::after {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #eee;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.tag:hover {
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
}

.tag:hover::after {
   border-left-color: crimson; 
}
```

```html
<h1>Tags</h1>

<h2>Example 1</h2>
<a href="#" class="tag">Front-end development</a>

<h2>Example 2</h2>
<ul class="tags">
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tag">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```